# Black icons after reinstalling Kubuntu desktop

Tags: kubuntu, plasma-5

After upgrading from Kubuntu 20.04 to Kubuntu 20.10, I could not login as it just showed a black screen after boot. So I switched to command line and reinstalled Kubuntu desktop with `sudo apt-get install --reinstall kubuntu-desktop kde-*`. After that, i was able to login and can use all applications but the icons and background of input boxes of system apps have turned black as shown below

[image]

Notice the black squares at the bottom right in the system tray, they used to be icons for Volume, Network, Bluetooth, etc. I can however click them and they behave as they used to. Also the desktop apps' icons are black.

[image]

Notice the input fields at the right of Layout, Wallpaer type and also the button backgrounds of the window.

After looking at some logs I noticed that Akonadi server was not starting up because of an unknown MySQL error and installed MariaDb as i read somewhere that it might help. Now I can start Akonadi server with `akonadictl` manually but still the same issue. I restarted plasma with `kquitapp5 plasmashell && kstart5 plasmashell` but still same issue. Also Akonadi does not start automatically when session begins.

Comment: I have the same issue with the recent Debian/testing upgrade to "KDE 5.19" [where suddenly all icons/images seems to be black only](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VhDSl.png). I wonder this could somehow being linked to rendering the SVG(?) alpha(?) channel wrongly. What graphics card are you using (on my end: Mesa Intel HD 5500)? As Debian's transition to Qt 5.15 may not be fully there yet, I also tried [this article](https://www.preining.info/blog/2020/11/debian-kde-plasma-status-2020-11-04/), however, the result did not change.

Comment: I encountered this on upgrade to jammy.
May be this bug(?) still not fixed.

Answer (score 20):

Found the solution [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/kde/comments/jhqbnz/kde_plasma_rendering_problem_black_squares/), as per the link in the link:

> Replacing libqt5quick5-gles with libqt5quick5 solved my problem

so make a: `sudo apt install libqt5quick5`
it worked for me on debian

Comment: I reinstalled so can't check if it works. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: You'll need to restart the computer afterwards.

Answer (score 12):

I encountered the same problem on Debian bullseye after a full-upgrade. The solution as pointed out by LuisF was to remove libqt5quick5-gles and then install libqt5quick5.

```
sudo service sddm stop
sudo apt remove libqt5quick5-gles
sudo apt install libqt5quick5
sudo service sddm start
```

Comment: worked in Kubuntu after upgrading from 20.10 to 21.04 (plasma 5.19 to 5.20), though I would only remove libqt5quick5-gles and install libqt5quick5, since stopping sddm freeze the system

Comment: Stopping sddm is just killing the display manager. You can switch to a different terminal with, for example, ctrl+alt+F2, and then log in and finish the job on the command line. Once you start sddm back up, the desktop will appear again.

Comment: This works for me. Thank you.  (I was uninstalled libllvm-12 on ubuntu 20.04 caused KDE problem)

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to install libqt5quick5, as given in other answers, *regardless* of whether libqt5quick5-gles was installed or not. Removing it, if it exists, is still necessary, because they conflict with each other.

On a failed upgrade from 20.10 to 21.04, I had the same symptoms, and the system couldn't automatically fix it. Installing libqt5quick5 with an sddm restart fixed it without a reboot.

Comment: On my system the gles-version was automatically removed when I installed the non-gles-version. So it might not be necessary to manually remove anything.