# After an apt-upgrade, my KDE dock/task manager icons in Kubuntu are all black

Tags: upgrade, kubuntu, kde, bug-reporting, 21.04

I recently ran `do-release-upgrade` to upgrade to Kubuntu 21.04 from 20.04 without issue. Other than some (expected) differences in configuration files, nothing failed. When I logged in to plasma, I was surprised to see all the sys tray's icons have been replaced with black placeholder squares -- see screenshot below. This is true even in alternative widgets, and in the the application launcher (all the icons are black squares).

[image: Broken kicker]
[image: Borken KDE]

There's nothing obvious in `/var/log/syslog` and I have an AMD gpu, which can happily run `glxgears`. The *closest* thing to a relevant error message is

```
Jun 14 22:01:49 localhost org.kde.KScreen[6021]: kscreen.xcb.helper: Event Error:  147
```

I'd love some help debugging this. Does anyone have any ideas? Should I report this to the devs, or will I be a hindrance?

Answer (score 1):

Mods, feel free to close this -- apologies; it is a dupe of this question (albeit in disguise!): [Black icons after reinstalling Kubuntu desktop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1288506/black-icons-after-reinstalling-kubuntu-desktop)

A quick installation of `sudo apt install libqt5quick5` fixed the problem. Do'h.