# Missing themes and icons Kubuntu 22.10

Tags: kubuntu, icons, themes, 22.10

My theme and icons has black boxes on my screen.

I have restarting my sddm and it has e
running status

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you change anything after which this came up?

Comment: My computer was had black screen. It wasn't boot up.

Comment: Did it not boot up right after installation? After some update?

Comment: So I uninstalled nvdia, xorg, xserver-xorg and kde. I reinstalled all of them in order to get back to those screen above

Comment: The only update it has perform was removing Linux 5.15.0-15 kernel

Comment: I have upgraded from 22.04 to 22.10. the current kernel I am using now us 5.15.0-21/23

Comment: I tried switching themes back to the basics. Still the same thing. I have tried switching between 0-21/23 kernels and I get the same thing

Comment: @Nmath Found the solution >>  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1288506/black-icons-after-reinstalling-kubuntu-desktop

Answer (score 1):

Replacing `libqt5quick5-gles` with `libqt5quick5` solved my problem:

To do this, run:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install libqt5quick5
```

Solution adapted from [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1291021).